# Java for loop array list not working

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

I'm making a tower defense game in Java but I have a problem with for loops and ArrayLists. I have a similar piece of code in my Tower.java class (used for buildings, stuff you use for shooting/defense):
`for (Enemy e : enemies) {
    shoot();
}`

Whenever my things shoot, they pick the last instance of Enemy.class and create a new instance of my Bullet.java class which then move towards the enemy (last  one in the arraylist). What I want is the tower/building to pick the first or nearest one and shoot towards it. Any ideas on how to do this?

**EDIT:**
Here's my Tower.java class: http://pastebin.com/uEiQ4F20

This problem is pretty much the same I have had in other projects as well. Basically, going through every instance of a class in an ArrayList seems to be not working very well, because whatever I do inside the loop, it only affects the last instance of the class in the ArrayList.

**EDIT:**
Apparently, someone removed the Enemy.java paste from pastebin, so here
it is again: http://pastebin.com/jMGNVBLQ

Comment: The loop does not seem to alter the way the shoot method behaves. Show the code for the shoot method.

Comment: You shoot once for each enemy, but that doesn't mean you shoot *at* some enemy.

Comment: And where exactly is the shoot(); method being called in the for loop. I don't see it anywhere..

Comment: @bot Are we looking at the same loop?

Comment: Your `for` loop can not be part of the code you posted on pastebin. There is a shoot method that takes parameters. At least I did not find one without parameters. So you have to be a little more precise on your problem. Just saying a for loop over a collection just affects the last element is, well, wrong. I assure you it will do exactly what you are telling it to for every element.

Comment: @Matze The for loop I posted here was just a demonstration of how it works, not the actual code I have.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved the problem by adding the following line of code:
`if (!enemy.removed && enemy == level.enemies.get(level.enemiesKilled))`